# how to render the file in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am new to symfony2 struked in some part

My question is i need to link to a separate page when i click on some button, my url is linking to that page but the fields in that page is not displaying

```
//controller(Action function)
public function displayAction(Request $request){
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $photos = new TcPhotos();
        $photos_form = $this->createForm(new PhotoType(), $photos);
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array('content' => $this->renderView('TcPhotoBundle:Default:display.html.twig',array('form' => $photos_form->createView()))));
        return $response;
    }else{
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array('content' => 'something went wrong'));
        return $response;
    }
}

//view.html.twig
<div><a href="#!{{ path('tc_photo_display') }}">more .....</a></div>


//root
tc_photo_display:
pattern: /display
defaults: { _controller: "TcPhotoBundle:Default:display" }
```

pls help me better solutions,i just needed to link that display page when i click more in view.html page

Comment: please provide your display.twig file, with this which data is contain you $photos variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can `render` any action of controller with this syntax in twig template:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', {
    'max': 3
})) }}
```

Or use `include` for simply including template from any other template:

```
{{ include(
    'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:articleDetails.html.twig',
    { 'article': article }
) }}
```

To read this [Including other Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates) will be usefull for you.

Comment: the thing is i m not able to get the values of that destination page, if i give include also it won't take

Comment: Maybe try to use a `service` with twig template injected dependence in it